Using Kubuntu 24.04 Whatsapp desktop on Opera and Firefox on snap or outside snap don't allow to download the files except PDF
Using Kubuntu 24.04  Whatsapp desktop on Opera on snap and Firefox on snap or outside snap don't allow to download any file. Opera download the PDF's Files only. How can I do?
